# Monitor internet connection using swiftui

Tags: networking, swiftui

I can't find what is wrong, I'm try to monitor the internet connectivity using swiftui.
I follow some tutorial online..

but it doest work for me.

can someone help me to find what is wrong on this code?

I'm using the simulator for testing, when I switch off the wifi of the iMac the variable isConnected still print out "we have internet!" when I switch on the wifi it print "no internet"

what is wrong in this code?

```
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    @Published var isConnected = true
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // codice eseguito sul thread principale
           
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                print("Yay! We have internet!")
            
                self.isConnected = true
            } else {
                print("NOOO! no internet!")
                self.isConnected = false
            }
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm = DataManager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if dm.isConnected == true {
                Text("connesso")
            } else {
                Text("non connesso")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it in a real device?

Comment: oh... I found in the real device it work correctly.. but in the simulator not working...sound very strange because in all tutorials I watched look working for them on the simulator... mystery..